# How to make a deformed trajectory smooth .

Tags: math, contour, spline

I am using Dynamic Time Warping to find the segments of the trajectory which do not match with the template trajectory .

Template Trajectory :

```
         .  . .
      .         . 
    .            .
  .               .
.                  .   .
                     .
```

Test Trajectory :

```
            .
          .   .
        .      .
      .         . 
    .            .
  .               .
.                  .   .
                     .
```

Using Dynamic Time Warping , i find the following points that do not match (marked with asterisk )

```
            *
          *   *
        .      .
      .         . 
    .            .
  .               .
.                  .   .
                     .
```

Now i want to enlarge the mistake what i do is ,
i multiply the x and y co-ordinates of the mistakes(non matched) points by a factor
x=x*1.2;
y=y*1.2;

this gives me a deformed trajectory like this :

```
         *
       *    *

    .        .
   .           . 
  .              .
 .                 .
.                    .    .
                        .
```

but i want a smooth trajectory , in which all the points are changed and the mistakes enlarged . something like this :

```
         *
       *    *
     .        .

   .             . 
  .                .
 .                  .
.                    .    .
                        .
```

How can i do this ?

PS:I really wasn't able to think of a simple way to describe the problem i am having. I am using C++ , if in anyway in explaining your solution .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define A(t) as the displacement vector at time=t.  The displacement vector for each point is then its position vector (x,y) minus the previous position vector.

Scale these vectors up to get your scaled error vector, and then move from point to point by adding the vectors together.  This will shift not only the range (y-axis) of the errors, but also the domain (x-axis) so it will look smooth.

Any use?